# Can epoll's EPOLLEXCLUSIVE trigger multiple reads on the same socket simultaneously?

Tags: linux, sockets, epoll

In my understanding EPOLLEXCLUSIVE will only wake one thread per event, but if more events happen it will retrigger.

Suppose I'm reading from multiple sockets using multiple threads, all using epoll_wait, with EPOLLEXCLUSIVE.

1. Data comes on socket S ==> thread A wakes
2. More data comes on Socket S ==> thread B wakes

If #2 happens before A is finished, it could be the case that A and B are reading from the socket simultaneously?

Is my understanding correct?